# Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here on overriding method and inheritance class

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, overriding, super

I am a new in Javascript and just start learning about overriding method and inheritance class, so I wrote this code and run it on the browser console and it just shows ' Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here '.
Here is the code:

```
  class Mail{
_contacts = [];
constructor(author){
    this.from = author;
}
sendMessagge = function(msg, to){
    console.log(`You send: ${msg} to ${to} from ${this.from}`);
    this._contacts.push(to);
}
showAllContacts(){
    return this._contacts;
}};

class whatsApp extends Mail{
constructor(username, isBusinessAccount, phone){
    super(phone);
    this.username = username;
    this.isBusinessAccount = isBusinessAccount;
}
myProfile = function(){
    return `username: ${this.username}, Type: ${this.isBusinessAccount? 'Business' : 'Personal'}, Phone: ${this.from}`;
}
sendMessagge = function(msg,to){
    super.sendMessagge(msg,to);
    console.log('Sent by WhastApp');
}};
```

and I believe that is something wrong with 'sendMessage' methods on the childclass whatsApp, because when I try to write the code like this :

```
sendMessagge(){
    super.sendMessagge();
    console.log('Sent by WhastApp');
}
```

its run on the browser console but its not work as im expected(its not showing 'Sent by whastApp').
Please give me some clue, i've looking for the solution on the internet but im not find the exact same case just like mine. And before that, thanks :)

Comment: you are defining a property named `sendMessage`, not a method. Use the syntax like `showAllContacts`

Comment: yeah, I just figured it out my mistake couple hours ago, omg I feel dumb lol, btw thanks for your answer/comment, thanks :)